# .load() multiple elements or .get() and place them in correct area

Tags: jquery, get, load

I am making this message viewer for my forum site. I have this code to start, i was orginally using .load() and now trying .get() having trouble figuring out how to do this work around.

Code I am working on

```
$('#message_holder').load('/privmsg?folder=inbox .tdtopics:lt(5)');
  $('#view_mess').click(function() {
     var msg = $('.tdtopics a').attr('href');
 $.get( msg, function() {
    $.each('div.posthead h2, .user-basic-info , .entry-content');
}, 'html');
     $('#mess_wrapper').show();
  });
});
```

So the `.each( -elements- );` I need to load these specifically from the url which is in the

`.get(msg` msg being the variable of course. I need to load these in my specific html each.

EX___

New Message

```
<div id="mess_wrapper">
 <div id="new_mess_pop">
  <div id="inner_mess_wrapper">
      <span id="post_date_time">-- div.posthead h2 element here --</span>
       <div id="users_contact_info">-- .user-basic-info element here --</div>
         <div id="message_post">-- .entry-content element here --</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
  <div id="message_holder">HIDDEN PLACE HOLDERS</div>
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the `.get()` and how to append them to the correct id automatically one the click event? I am teaching myself everything, so if someone can give me a good explanation and how to go about this it would be very grateful!

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but that code does'nt make much sense? There's no data parameter in the `$.get` function, the `$.each` function does'nt really do anything etc.

Comment: You are probably correct ;) first time with `.get()` any better suggestions?

Comment: eehm, not really, as I have no idea what it is you're trying to do ?

Comment: Trying to load the elements listed such as `.postedhead h2` and have it placed in my id of `post_date_time` I had this working with using 

.load(msg , " .post"); though it grabbed the entire thing and it is defeating the purpose of me trying to make this code actually work.

Comment: It's just guessing, but maybe something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ3n7/) ???

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I wanted. I have to study your code. I see you add 1. `function(data)` which I've never done before the only thing I've done is `function(e)` are they the same thing? And how to write upon it for later uses if need be

Comment: No, $.get is an ajax function, and the data parameter is the actual HTML returned from the server.

Comment: Ok well post your answer and I'll upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#view_mess').click(function() {
  var msg = $('.tdtopics a').attr('href');
  $.get(msg, function (data) {
      var elems = $(data);
      $('#post_date_time').append(elems.find('div.posthead h2'));
      $('#users_contact_info').append(elems.find('.user-basic-info'));
      $('#message_post').append(elems.find('.entry-content'));
  }, 'html');
  $('#mess_wrapper').show();
});
```